# How to control sigilent power supply SPD3303X using python or windows cmd

Tags: python

Is there any way to control sigilent power supply SPD3303X to set voltage or get voltage etc. using python or windows cmd?

Tried with [PyVISA](https://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/stable) and [python-ivi](https://github.com/python-ivi/python-ivi) libraries but am just able to read the connected device name nothing further

Comment: What commands or scripts have you tried so far and what was the result?

Comment: I have tried below code with PyVISA

Comment: [PyVISA_link](https://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#an-example)